# Rectifying a controller for not adding empty values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm tryng out a CRUD with AngularJS ([Project](https://samu101108.github.io/MandaCRUDs/usuarios.html)) and I saw that when I press 'Cadastrar' button, it keeps pushing into the array even if it is empty.
What I want is to prevent this behavior to occur.

```
      $scope.add = function(){
      $scope.listProducts.push(
  {
    codigo:$scope.codigo, nome:$scope.nome, email:$scope.email, login:$scope.login
  });
    $scope.codigo = '';
    $scope.nome = '';
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.login = '';
    };
```

what should be a good thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a short way, you should test the properties that are required before `push`.

**Ex:**

```
if ($scope.codigo && $scope.nome && $scope.email && $scope.login) {
  $scope.listProducts.push({
    codigo: $scope.codigo, 
    nome: $scope.nome, 
    email: $scope.email, 
    login: $scope.login
  });
}
```

Comment: It's a pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your $scope.codigo is undefined when pushing to the array. If you want to prevent it push into array.

You have to use condition like angular.isDefined($scope.codigo) and it condition satisfies then only it push the data into array.

You can calculate $scope.codigo depends opon the number of items present in your list.

```
if( angular.isDefined($scope.codigo)){
$scope.listProducts.push(
  {
    codigo:$scope.codigo, nome:$scope.nome, email:$scope.email, login:$scope.login
  });
    $scope.codigo = '';
    $scope.nome = '';
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.login = '';
    };
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know about .isDefined(), now it is worth, Thank you!